# Any idea why ids are ignored with JPQL query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

In a JPA repository, the following method is defined:

```
  @Query(
      "SELECT s FROM Site s "
          + "LEFT JOIN FETCH s.siteType "
          + "LEFT JOIN FETCH s.variables "
          + "LEFT JOIN FETCH s.parameters")
  List<Site> findWithDetails();
```

On my computer, this JPQL query is translated correctly:

```
select
    site0_.id_site as id_site1_37_0_,
    sitetype1_.id_site_type as id_site_1_39_1_,
    variables2_.id_variable as id_varia1_50_2_,
    parameters3_.id_site_param as id_site_1_38_3_,
    site0_.active as active2_37_0_,
    site0_.coord as coord3_37_0_,
    site0_.name as name4_37_0_,
    site0_.short_name as short_na5_37_0_,
    site0_.id_site_type as id_site_7_37_0_,
    site0_.source as source6_37_0_,
    sitetype1_.display_name as display_2_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_default_color as marker_d3_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_fa_icon as marker_f4_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_fa_icon_color as marker_f5_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_fa_icon_prefix as marker_f6_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_shape as marker_s7_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.site_type as site_typ8_39_1_,
    variables2_.active as active2_50_2_,
    variables2_.description as descript3_50_2_,
    variables2_.id_external_ts_source as id_exter9_50_2_,
    variables2_.frequency as frequenc4_50_2_,
    variables2_.name as name5_50_2_,
    variables2_.popup_display_order as popup_di6_50_2_,
    variables2_.short_name as short_na7_50_2_,
    variables2_.id_site as id_site10_50_2_,
    variables2_.unit_type as unit_typ8_50_2_,
    variables2_.id_variable_type as id_vari11_50_2_,
    variables2_.id_site as id_site10_50_0__,
    variables2_.id_variable as id_varia1_50_0__,
    parameters3_.name as name2_38_3_,
    parameters3_.id_site as id_site4_38_3_,
    parameters3_.value as value3_38_3_,
    parameters3_.id_site as id_site4_38_1__,
    parameters3_.id_site_param as id_site_1_38_1__
from
    site site0_
left outer join site_type sitetype1_ on
    site0_.id_site_type = sitetype1_.id_site_type
left outer join variable variables2_ on
    site0_.id_site = variables2_.id_site
left outer join site_param parameters3_ on
    site0_.id_site = parameters3_.id_site
```

On my colleague's computer, it translates as:

```
select
    site0_.id_site as id_site1_37_0_,
    sitetype1_.id_site_type as id_site_1_39_1_,
    variables2_.id_variable as id_varia1_50_2_,
    parameters3_.id_site_param as id_site_1_38_3_,
    site0_.active as active2_37_0_,
    site0_.coord as coord3_37_0_,
    site0_.name as name4_37_0_,
    site0_.short_name as short_na5_37_0_,
    site0_.source as source6_37_0_,
    sitetype1_.display_name as display_2_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_default_color as marker_d3_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_fa_icon as marker_f4_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_fa_icon_color as marker_f5_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_fa_icon_prefix as marker_f6_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.marker_shape as marker_s7_39_1_,
    sitetype1_.site_type as site_typ8_39_1_,
    variables2_.active as active2_50_2_,
    variables2_.description as descript3_50_2_,
    variables2_.frequency as frequenc4_50_2_,
    variables2_.name as name5_50_2_,
    variables2_.popup_display_order as popup_di6_50_2_,
    variables2_.short_name as short_na7_50_2_,
    variables2_.unit_type as unit_typ8_50_2_,
    variables2_.id_site as id_site10_50_0__,
    variables2_.id_variable as id_varia1_50_0__,
    parameters3_.name as name2_38_3_,
    parameters3_.value as value3_38_3_,
    parameters3_.id_site as id_site4_38_1__,
    parameters3_.id_site_param as id_site_1_38_1__
from
    site site0_
left outer join site_type sitetype1_ on
    site0_.id_site_type = sitetype1_.id_site_type
left outer join variable variables2_ on
    site0_.id_site = variables2_.id_site
left outer join site_param parameters3_ on
    site0_.id_site = parameters3_.id_site
```

Request created on my collegue's computer is not working because the following lines are missing:

```
site0_.id_site_type as id_site_7_37_0_,
variables2_.id_external_ts_source as id_exter9_50_2_,
variables2_.id_site as id_site10_50_2_,
variables2_.id_variable_type as id_vari11_50_2_,
parameters3_.id_site as id_site4_38_3_,
```

Any idea where to look? Is there a missing configuration somewhere? I don't understand why these id lines are missing.

We both use Spring-Boot 2.7.0, which includes Spring-Data 2.7.0.

Regards

François

Comment: It should still properly map to a `Site` object no? Do you have any error message?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer There is no error message. Because these id lines are missing in the query, `Site` objects are loaded without any FK. When JPA tries to access missing information, it launches numerous requests. As you could imagine, it makes data display slower.

Comment: The JPQL are generated based on the model and the Hibernate ORM version you are using. If the query is different it means that you have two different entity models or you are using two different Hibernate ORM versions. If you are deploying this on a server, make sure that you both are using the same version.

Comment: The fields exists and are used in the joins: "site0_.id_site_type = sitetype1_.id_site_type" has site0_.id_site_type, so technically isn't needed for the select since the information is there in each row. Why are requests on your collegue's computer not working exactly - what requests are launched and when? Does this problem occur with all queries or just this one?

Comment: @Chris The problem occurs on every table where an equivalent query is defined in its specific repository. Requests are called in the MVC layer, when displaying data on a web page.

Comment: I still do not follow: what exactly is the outcome? Is it trying to fetch the s.siteType relationship again or something else?